# How to disable drag scrolling but keep mouse wheel scrolling for ListView in Flutter MacOS?

Tags: flutter

So when I set `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` on `ListView.builder`, it also disables mouse wheel scrolling. Is there a way to keep mouse wheel but disable drag?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `Listener` widget to watch for drag events happening on your `ListView` and manually scroll the `ListView` to desired offset using `ScrollController` attached to that `ListView`.

Here is a sample code:

```
Listener(
          onPointerSignal: (ps) {
            if (ps is PointerScrollEvent) {
              _controller.animateTo(ps.position.dy,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  curve: Curves.linear);
            }
          },
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              controller: _controller,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                    height: 100,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    color: index.isEven ? Colors.blue : Colors.green);
              }))
```

And here is a [link](https://dartpad.dev/0c944d8f6e9976cb61ca246c5d314dfa) to a working demo ( You may have to play around with listener events to make the scrolling perfect, this is just an example)

Comment: Thanks for the code and tips! Any idea if they are going to eventually include an option like this into Flutter? Seems like sensible default behavior for desktop apps.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for the answer (@HasilT), it helped! I found that `PointerScrollEvent.scrollDelta` is already "animated", and you can use it with `ScrollController.jumpTo`. In my code, I prevent overscroll with `min` and `max` functions.

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

Listener(
  onPointerSignal: (ps) {
    if (ps is PointerScrollEvent) {
      final newOffset = _controller.offset + ps.scrollDelta.dy;
      if (ps.scrollDelta.dy.isNegative) {
        _controller.jumpTo(math.max(0, newOffset));
      } else {
        _controller
            .jumpTo(math.min(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent, newOffset));
      }
    }
  },
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 100,
    controller: _controller,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
          height: 100,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          color: index.isEven ? Colors.blue : Colors.green);
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: this is great cuz it works on SingleChildScrollView ty

Answer (score 2):

Feature request has been created for this case:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71322

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap in a widget @truthmast's solution

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:responsive_builder/responsive_builder.dart';

class DragPreventingSingleChildScrollView extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = ScrollController();
  final Widget child;

  DragPreventingSingleChildScrollView({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ResponsiveBuilder(
        builder: (c, si) => !si.isDesktop
            ? SingleChildScrollView(child: child)
            : Listener(
                onPointerSignal: (ps) {
                  if (ps is PointerScrollEvent) {
                    final newOffset = _controller.offset + ps.scrollDelta.dy;
                    if (ps.scrollDelta.dy.isNegative) {
                      _controller.jumpTo(math.max(0, newOffset));
                    } else {
                      _controller.jumpTo(math.min(
                          _controller.position.maxScrollExtent, newOffset));
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: _controller,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  child: child,
                ),
              ),
      );
}
```